# s3cmd multipart chunk-size memory management

Tags: s3cmd

I was wondering how to predict how much memory s3cmd is going to use to upload a given file. I'm concerned that for large files it could use too much system memory. And if I increase the chunk size, will it use more memory per chunk/multipart?

I checked the documentation

https://s3tools.org/s3cmd

but couldn't find anything related to memory management.

I've experimented and tried to upload a 200GB file with something like

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd put largefile_200G.txt s3://mybucket/testlargefile/largefile_200G.txt --multipart-chunk-size-mb=250
```

and what I've seen myself is that the memory usage for the created process was constant and chosen proportionally to the available memory on the server (the more is available on the server the more it is allocated for the s3cmd process).

Does someone happen to know roughly how the memory management works and if it will always be constant like in the experiment I've tried (without spikes that is)?